# How to work with sites using with or without htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

There's xampp setup in the office in which php sites doesn't use a rewrite engine. It works fine, but since I'll be working with mvc setup, is it possible to work in 1 xampp environment in which the old setup is retained but on the other hand you can use a rewrite engine on other php sites? Cause whenever I include a .htaccess to use the rewriteengine, the site goes Server Error.

TIA

Comment: what is the server error in error.log?

Comment: I don't have the laptop now and haven't seen the error log. Where is this located btw. But for the error message, it prompted me this: 
"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script."

Comment: Found the error log. It says something about RewriteEngine, turned it on, and it now works. Thanks for directing me where to look

Comment: no problem. just update your question as solved